# Heathrow T5 to King's cross via Paddington vs. Piccadilly

Tags: public-transport, london, lhr, cambridge

I know that this has been asked before, but the answers are quite old. Next Tuesday I arrive at Heathrow airport terminal 5 around 12:30 noon. I have purchased a "peak off return" ticket to Cambridge which I need to collect at a machine. It recommends taking the Express line to Paddington and then the tube to King's cross. At the same time, there is a warning that the tube might be crowded and delayed. Now I realized that there is a direct (but slower connection) via Piccadilly line. What do you prefer? Is my ticket valid for this alternative? I've never been to London.

EDIT after the journey: I wasn't able to enter Piccadilly line with my peak off return ticket (doors didn't open). I had to take the Express line to Paddington, but it was super easy to find and probably much faster anyway.

Comment: Opinion? I never use the so-called express to Paddington. If you also have to use the tube, you might as well get on it in the first place. The direct route from Heathrow to Kings Cross takes one hour by Picadilly Line. Tickets are usually for "any reasonable route". Another advantage for those unfamiliar with London is you only have to find one train. And 12:30 noon isn't a peak travel time.

Comment: An exception might be if you have a lot of luggage, when the train is easier, and then take a taxi from Paddington to Kings Cross.

Comment: As you say, this has been asked before, does this answer your question? [How to get from Heathrow Airport to King's Cross, London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16960/how-to-get-from-heathrow-airport-to-kings-cross-london) Nothing significant has changed since then.

Comment: @djr yes this does indeed answer the question, given that nothing has changed in 9 years (which surprises me)
Thanks for all the comments

Comment: Note for future readers: Given the date of OP's travel (early May 2022) the linked duplicate question is still up to date. The opening of the core section of Crossrail / Elizabeth Line by (hopefully) June 2022 would open up new interchange options (e.g. via Paddington & Farringdon) between the Heathrow-King's Cross and Heathrow-Cambridge journeys. The new route features mainline trains and is hence luggage friendly. Someone unfamiliar with London might experience slight difficulty in finding the trains and navigating the fare restrictions though.